# Generating lots of Examples in Polynomials Rings

Tags: polynomials

I'm studying polynomial rings and i would like to know some tricks for generating lots of examples.

For instance, suppose i'm interested in polynomials over the integers mod (2,x^3 + 1). To get a feel for the structure i would like to expand a bunch of random polynomials and see what happens.

I would like to do this without typing each individually.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok. Well what i do now is go like  Expand[(5 x + 43/5) (23 x - 45/2) (12 x + 90/2)] and see what happens. Use the PolynomialMod function on it see what i get. But this is just one example. I want to generate lots of examples. And i dont want to do it by typing each one out. I just want to know how i would go about generating lots of examples like the one i just discussed, which was just a random polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hopefully will get you started. It asks for the polynomial order, generate random integers from `1` to `10` for the coefficients of the polynomial, then uses `FromDigits` to build the polynomial in x. It also asks for the `Mod` integer value to use. It then calls `PolynomialMod` and shows the original polynomial and the polynomial mod the integer.

Not pretty, just a quick hack. Just to first see if this is what you want before going more.

```
Manipulate[
 doit;

 Module[{p, m},
  p = makePolynomial[n, x];
  m = PolynomialMod[p, mod];

  Grid[{
    {"polynomial", Expand[p]},
    {Row[{"polynomial mod ", mod}], m}
    }, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]
  ],

 {{n, 2, "polynomial order"}, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{mod, 2, "mod"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Button["make another", doit = Date[], ImageSize -> 100],
 ContentSize -> {550, 80},

 Initialization :>
  (
   makePolynomial[n_Integer, x_Symbol] := Module[{z, c},
     z = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] RandomInteger[{1, 10}];
     c = Table[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}], {n}];
     FromDigits[Reverse[AppendTo[c, z]], x]
     ]
   )
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yah thats exactly the kinda of thing i'm looking for. Thanks for getting me started :).